# Xamarin.Forms Shell Back Button Disable Animation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently building an app where I want no animations when Popping and Pushing in Navigation in Shell.

I got it down for Push Pages, as that's a simply "False" statement to the function, however overriding the Back Button functionality doesn't seem to have any affect on Popping Animation.

The following should override the back buttons of all Pages in the application, to do a Pop with no animation, however there's still an animation happening.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Current.Navigation.PopAsync(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open bug with Xamarin which can be found in this [Github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3054).

From what I understand the xamarin team thinks this is a breaking change and it might take some time to fix.

**Suggestion**

There is a comment there that uses a Custom Renderer to fix this in the following way:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.Droid
{
public class CNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
    public CNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPushAsync(view, false);
    }

    protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, false);
    }

    protected override Task<bool> OnPopToRootAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPopToRootAsync(page, false);
    }
}
}
```

> Do the same thing for other platforms. As I said, this is making the animated flag in Core useless, but at least it disables all page animations even when you use the Back button because it should call OnPopViewAsync.
>
> You could potentially add custom logic here to scan for page types or a certain set of criteria (like your custom logic [i.e. non-animated push should be coupled with a non-animated pop for that specific page]).

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: Cool, would you also happen to have an example for iOS? :)

Comment: I do not have it with me but I will try to find it out, will get back to you in case I find anything.